# Cannot read property 'rejected' of undefined | ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My `Login.js` file was getting larger and larger so I decided to create a reusable component in a separate file, `LoginForm.js`. However, after I extracted the previous code from `Login.js` into `LoginForm.js` one of my props is getting undefined and I have no idea why.

**The prop who's is getting undefined:** `this.props.token`

I've imported all the modules and compared the code, and everything seems to be correct.

### File 1

In `Login.js` I have this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createToken } from '../../actions/tokenActions'
import LoginForm from './LoginForm'

// Styles
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography'
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card'
import Button from 'material-ui/Button'
import { CircularProgress } from 'material-ui/Progress'
import injectSheet from 'react-jss'

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
  }
  onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.createToken(this.state)
  }
  render() {
    const progressBar = this.props.token.pending
      ? <CircularProgress className={this.props.progress} />
      : ''

    return (
      <div className="box" style={{ margin: '100px auto', width: '300px' }}>
        {progressBar}
        <form
          onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)}
          style={{ display: this.props.token.pendling ? 'none' : 'block' }}
        >
          <LoginForm />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapState = state => {
  return {
    token: state.token
  }
}

const mapDispatch = (dispatch, props) => ({
  createToken: data => dispatch(createToken(data))
})

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Login)
```

### File 2

And in my other file, `LoginForm.js` I have this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createToken } from '../../actions/tokenActions'

//Styles
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card'
import Button from 'material-ui/Button'
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography'

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
  }

  onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.createToken(this.state)
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.token)
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography
            style={{
              fontSize: '40px',
              fontWeight: '300',
              color: '#636363',
              marginBottom: '20px'
            }}
            type="subheading"
            gutterBottom
            align="center"
          >
            Logga In
          </Typography>

          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Email"
            onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Lösenord"
            onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
          />

          <Button
            raised
            color="primary"
            onClick={this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)}
            className="text-center"
          >
            Skicka
          </Button>
          {this.props.token.rejected
            ? 'Felaktigt användarnamn eller lösenord'
            : ''}
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
```

I bet it's a really basic question, but I have no other to ask than here. I am really grateful for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<LoginForm />` doesnt provide any props.

`this.props` wouldn't be undefined if you provided it like this: `<LoginForm token={this.props.token} />` props doesnt get passed on if you dont explicit write it, you can write them one by one but you can also type like this: `<LoginForm {...this.props} />`

Comment: Well.. That was an awkward miss haha! Will accept your answer as soon as possible!